# Special JPEG Not Supported in PHP?

Tags: php, jpeg, mime

I've created an upload form in PHP (with a whitelist of MIME types), but during testing I encountered a 'special' JPEG that doesn't seem to work. PHP doesn't seem to pick up a MIME type for it.

Can you tell me, are there any 'special' jpeg types? I couldn't find anything on Google that seems to be related to this.

Many thanks,

Sam

EDIT: I opened the file in paint.net and saved a copy using the paint.net default settings for JPEG and this file has uploaded fine.

Comment: The JPEG standard supports many options that are not commonly supported. Post a sample image and I can probably tell you why the original image was rejected.

Comment: It isn't going to be possible to tell you what is wrong with a file based on having access to the results of opening that file, editing it, then re-encoding it as JPEG.

Comment: to my understanding there is only one and the Mime type is "image/jpeg"

Comment: If you really can't find an error (in the logs etc) I'd suggest to check the file ending and try to open the file with GD lib or Imagick when there is no mime type. If it can be opened with GD lib then it actually is an image.

Comment: I've checked the error logs and nothing comes up. Is there anything you can suggest that I can check for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the explanation you have given, specifically that the file read (apparently without errors) and after saving you could use it fine, the most likely problems were:

1. The file is a progressive JPEG and your decoder does not support progressive.
2. The file used a sampling setting your decoder does not support.
3. The file used a file format your decoder does not support (there are multiple JPEG file formats).
4. (Less likely) the file is in JPEG 2000 format.